# Database table design best practice for update_date NOT NULL constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-design

I have database table contains **updated_date** column as below.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  created_date timestamp NOT NULL,
  updated_date timestamp,
  isactive smallint DEFAULT 1,
  version smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT table_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Please suggest `updated_date timestamp NOT NULL` is best practice?

Comment: It's best practice if you don't want/need to record when the record was updated.  So, is the update timestamp mandatory according to your business logic?

Comment: According to logic when record is created created date is added & when record updated then updated date is added. Is it best practice when record is created same timestamp add to both created_date & updated_date?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with doing this, unless you need to identify records which were just created, in which case maybe `NULL` would have some special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on how you are going to use those columns.

I see nothing wrong with declaring the column `NOT NULL` and using the same `created_date` and `updated_date` when a record is created (I would have chosen names that do not contain “date” though).

I think that it is a good habit to have columns `NOT NULL` if that is possible for the application without bending its arm (a bad example would be using `1970-01-01 00:00:00` to represent missing data). It usually makes queries simpler and hence more efficient if they don't have to deal with NULL values.